# Python's Requests or Mechanize to login to a site

Tags: python, mechanize, python-requests, mechanize-python

I want to start off by apologizing. I know this has more than likely been done more than enough times, and I'm just beating a dead horse, but I'd really like to know how to get this to work. I am trying to use the Requests module for python in order to login to a website and verify that it works. I'm also using BeautifulSoup in the code in order to find some strings that I have to use to process the request.

I'm getting hung up on how to properly form the header. What exactly is necessary in the header information?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.session()
requester = session.get('http://iweb.craven.k12.nc.us/index.php')
soup = BeautifulSoup(requester.text)
ps = soup.find_all('input')
def getCookieInfo():
    result = []
    for item in ps:
        if (item.attrs['name'] == 'return' and item.attrs['type'] == 'hidden'):
            strcom = item.attrs['value']
            sibling = item.next_sibling.next_sibling.attrs['name']
            result.append(strcom)
            result.append(sibling)
    return result
cookiedInfo=getCookieInfo()
payload =   [('username','myUsername'), 
         ('password','myPassword'), 
         ('Submit','Log in'), 
         ('option','com_users'), 
         ('task','user.login'), 
         ('return', cookiedInfo[0]),
         (cookiedInfo[1], '1')
        ]

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Origin':'http://iweb.craven.k12.nc.us',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)'
}

r = session.post('http://iweb.craven.k12.nc.us/index.php', data=payload, headers=headers)
r = session.get('http://iweb.craven.k12.nc.us')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
```

Also if it would be better/more pythonic to utilize the mechanize module I would be open to suggestions.

Comment: Ouch, that looks hard. Have you heard of Selenium webdriver? You can use Python to drive an actual browser. Avoids you having to handle cookies and sessions.

Comment: Wow, that is extremely simple. Do you know of anyway to keep it from displaying the browser?

Comment: Under linux you can use a virtual frame buffer (Xvfb) as the display manager. I do that all the time for headless testing. Windows? No idea.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your problem is here. Is this working? Not working? If not working, what's the symptom of failure? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: @Lukasa The problem is that it fails to log me in. I've tried a good number of different options to include in the header I'm sending, but I can never replicate the header information as I would have sent it via visiting the webpage physically.

I've had to capture the packet while physically logging in as well as while running this code for comparison, but I just haven't gotten the pieces to fit together the right way.

My question is: "What role does header information/cookie information play in this transaction?"

Comment: Just complementing the answer about the Selenium headless execution, you can use [PhantomJS webdriver](https://realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/), it'll do the trick.